# How to add two variables passed in the shell which returns integer count?

Tags: shell, shell-script

In my script I am using 2 variables:

```
integer CCD_COUNT1= `grep '.CCD' $TMP_RPT_FILE1 | wc-l`
```

It returns integer value suppose `47`.

Another variable:

```
integer CCD_COUNT=`grep '.CCD' $TMP_RPT_FILE | wc -L `
```

It also returns integer value suppose `1`.

How to add the integers `$CCD_COUNT1` and `$CCD_COUNT`, so that it will give `48`?

Comment: Forget shell scripting, definitely use jquery for that... http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif

Comment: I don't know how to use jquery . I need to do using shell scripting . @chaos

Answer (score 16):

If you have 2 variable, let say `$a` and `$b`:

```
a=5
b=7
```

You can sum them by:

```
c=$((a+b))
```

`$c` contains now the value 12:

```
echo $c
12
```

Comment: I did count = $CCD_COUNT1 + $CCD_COUNT but it didn't work @chaos

Comment: Yes, but that's not how I wrote in my answer. Please read my answer

Comment: Count=$((CCD_COUNT1+CCD_COUNT))  you are telling me to try this way @chaos??

Comment: If those 2 variables contain the numbers, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **`expr`**:

```
NAME
       expr - evaluate expressions

SYNOPSIS
       expr EXPRESSION
       expr OPTION

 ARG1 + ARG2

              arithmetic sum of ARG1 and ARG2
```

Example:

```
$ expr $CCD_COUNT + $CCD_COUNT1
$ 48
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want bash don't use subprocess, you can use (( )):

```
(( RESULT = CCD_COUNT1 + $CCD_COUNT ))
echo $RESULT
```

This page contains the description: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/arithmetic_eval

Note: apparently this solution is not specified by POSIX (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let)